# Connecting/synchronizing input/form fields in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a couple of form fields that are related to each other which I would like to all get updated based on a single selection using the `<select>` element.

Say that a user selects a specific country in a form field, I then want the `countryCode` field and the `currency` field to get updated in relation to what country the user selected.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<select name="country" ng-options="item.country for item in countries">
   <option value="">Pick a country</option>
</select>

<input name="countryCode" type="text" placeholder="Country Code">
<input name="currency" type="text" placeholder="Currency">
```

**Angular**

```
.controller('exampleCtrl', function {
  $scope.countries = [
    { country: "Sweden" },
    { country: "USA" },
    { country: "Canada" }
  ];

  $scope.currencies = [
    { currency: "SEK" },
    { currency: "USD" },
    { currency: "CAD" }
  ];

  $scope.countryCodes = [
    { countryCode: "SE" },
    { countryCode: "US" },
    { countryCode: "CA" }
  ];

});
```

I'm guessing the most obvious way would be the use of the ng-model directive but I'm already using it to collect the information for each of the form elements to validate the form and send to the server.

How would I go about solving this in a smart way using Angular.js?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it - hope it helps!

Markup

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <select name="country" ng-options="item.country for item in countries" ng-model="currentItem" ng-change="updateVals()">
            <option value="">Pick a country</option>
        </select>

        <input name="countryCode" type="text" placeholder="Country Code" ng-model="currentCode">
        <input name="currency" type="text" placeholder="Currency" ng-model="currentCurrency">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function Ctrl($scope) {

    $scope.countries = [
    { country: "Sweden",  currency: "SEK", countryCode: "SE" },
    { country: "USA", currency: "USD", countryCode: "US" },
    { country: "Canada", currency: "CAD", countryCode: "CA" }
  ];


    $scope.updateVals = function() {
        if ($scope.currentItem) {
          $scope.currentCurrency = $scope.currentItem.currency;
            $scope.currentCode = $scope.currentItem.countryCode;
        } else {
            $scope.currentCurrency = undefined;   
            $scope.currentCode = undefined;
        }
    }

}
```

And here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/18965/

**Updated fiddle to make everything shorter:**

http://jsfiddle.net/sx7xnoyr/1/

Comment: Yes thank you that is exactly what I wanted! :)

Thanks!

Comment: Here - this is even better / shorter

http://jsfiddle.net/sx7xnoyr/1/

like this you can just get the values from $scope.currentItem - you don't need the other variables.